# Rails - MySql app - Reporting and Charting requirements

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, charts, report

I have a Rails app with MySql DB.  It houses a lot of data on which we need to run some reports and create some dashboards.  It requires some calculations.  What are some ready to use solutions for this?  Gems, tools or frameworks that can help getting it developed fast would help.

Answer (score 0):

For charts you can use Fusion chart gem in rails 
https://github.com/fusioncharts/rails-wrapper
In order to draw charts you need data in hash Like
Create one lib which will return hash data 
example

```
class Dashboard
   def initialize
     # initialize here
   end

   def data_set
     {
        user_details: User.details,
        profile_details: Profile.details
     } 
   end 

end
```

In particular model you can fetch data using queries.
For charts, you have to render charts as per documentation

Comment: Thanks @Minakshi Najardhane.  Charting is one of my concerns.  I am more worried about the Data handling part of it.